# SQL - Get distinct, newest rows by grouping multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, group-by

I have a database table which looks something like this (I've removed the irrelevant fields)

```
[dbo].[UserMessage]
(
    [OwnerUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FromUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreationDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
)
```

In this table i have the following data

```
OwnerUserId    FromUserId    ToUserId    CreationDateTime   
13             13            15          2013-06-26 13:58:01.0270000
15             13            15          2013-06-26 13:58:24.0770000
13             15            13          2013-06-26 14:08:58.0070000
15             15            13          2013-06-26 14:08:43.8570000
13             13            15          2013-06-26 14:09:15.1030000
15             13            15          2013-06-26 14:09:26.2000000
13             15            13          2013-06-26 14:09:47.0030000
15             15            13          2013-06-26 14:09:38.1330000
13             13            16          2013-06-26 14:20:27.5170000
16             13            16          2013-06-26 14:20:41.0130000
```

What i want is an sql query that returns the newest distinct message for a particle owner between distinct users.
So if i wanted all the conversations for OwnerUserId = 13, i'd want the result returned to be

```
OwnerUserId    FromUserId    ToUserId    CreationDateTime
13             13            16          2013-06-26 14:20:27.5170000
13             15            13          2013-06-26 14:09:47.0030000
```

If i wanted all the conversations for OwnerUserId = 15, i'd want the result returned to be

```
OwnerUserId    FromUserId    ToUserId    CreationDateTime
15             15            13          2013-06-26 14:09:38.1330000
```

If i wanted all the conversations for OwnerUserId = 16, i'd want the result returned to be

```
OwnerUserId    FromUserId    ToUserId    CreationDateTime
16             13            16          2013-06-26 14:20:41.0130000
```

I've created a query that looks like this for [OwnerUserId] = 13

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerUserId, fromUserId, ToUserId ORDER BY CreationDateTime DESC) AS rn
   FROM [UserMessage]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
and [OwnerUserId] = 13;
```

but this query returns

```
OwnerUserId    FromUserId    ToUserId    CreationDateTime               rn
13             13            15          2013-06-26 14:09:15.1030000    1
13             13            16          2013-06-26 14:20:27.5170000    1
13             15            13          2013-06-26 14:09:47.0030000    1
```

I dont want the top row being return because the last row already represents the same conversation (albeit the FromUserID and ToUserId are inversed).
Any ideas?
The solution should work for any [OwnerUserId] (I've used 13 as an example)

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!ANSWER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (
       PARTITION BY OwnerUserId, 
       CHECKSUM(CASE WHEN ToUserId > fromUserId THEN (convert(varchar(256),ToUserId) + ':' + convert(varchar(256),fromUserId)) ELSE (convert(varchar(256),fromUserId) + ':' + convert(varchar(256),ToUserId)) END) 
       ORDER BY CreationDateTime desc
    ) AS rn
    FROM [UserMessage]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
and [OwnerUserId] = 13;
```

I arrived at the solution by using checksum in the partition of the query.
Basically i combine the fromUserId and toUserId to create a unique identifier for a conversation. By partitioning on OwnerUserId and the new identifer, i can group together conversations.

Comment: What should be the result if `[OwnerUserId] = 16`?

Comment: The result for OwnerUserId = 16 should be 16,13,16,2013-06-26 14:20:41.0130000. Just one row

Comment: The result for OwnerUserId = 15 should be one row 15,15,13,2013-06-26 14:09:38.1330000.

Comment: So you mean row 15, 13, 15, 2013-06-26 14:09:26.000 should not be in the result?

Comment: If [OwnerUserId] = 16 then row 15, 13, 15, 2013-06-26 14:09:26.000 should not be in the result.